# PhpSpreadsheet force download file not working - bad format

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

**Problem**:
The created (XLSX) file is send to email and works well but it doesn't not open when I download it using this script, MS Excel shows "invalid file format or extension" error.

I wrote a script to force download an excel file from the server if there is a `$_GET` and send it by email if there isn't.

```
$writer = new Xlsx( $spreadsheet );
$writer->save( 'file.xlsx' );
$file_path = PATH_TO_FILE; // for example purposes

if( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && 'download' == $_GET['action'] ) {
    // force download file
    if( file_exists( $file_path ) ) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" ' . basename( $file_path ) . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file_path ) );
        flush(); // Flush system output buffer
        readfile( $file_path );
        exit;
    }
}
else {
    // send email
    $to = 'example@example';
    $subject = 'subject';
    $body = 'body ' . date( 'd-m-Y' );
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: John Doe <info@example.com>',
    );
    $attachment = array( $file_path );

    $result = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment );
    if( !$result ) {
        error_log( '$result: ' . print_r( $result, true ) );
    }
}
```

*`PATH_TO_FILE` leads to the actual file

Any idea why the file download script generates a bad excel file?

Thanks!

Comment: TIP: open the downloaded file in plain text editor, sometimes there is an error written inside ;)

Comment: @ino it shows me some `<style>` tags I have at the head of the file. I assume that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ino's tip I managed to solve this.

You **have to make sure** there is no HTML/CSS/JS before the PHP tags.